# Why do we involve the left-hand derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I've always thought of slope as "change in y as x increases by 1," so when I think of the slope at a point on a curve, I think of "how would y change as x increases by 1 from this point on." The left-hand derivative kind of seems backwards to me, like "at what rate did y change at in order to get to this point." Why do we force a double-sided limit to exist for differentiability? Why do we need both derivatives to be equal? Please help me understand this.

Comment: You are thinking at too large a scale. These are, after all, limits. You my consider it a matter of continuity of the derivative

Answer (score 4):

> Why do we force a double-sided limit to exist for differentiability?

There's a general pattern in mathematics that the narrower your definitions are, the easier they are to use. If derivatives are defined using two-sided limits, then you can state a theorem like the chain rule as simply "the derivative of the composite is the product of the derivatives". But if derivatives are defined using one-sided limits, then you have to say something like "the derivative of the composite is the product of the derivatives, provided that the inner derivative is nonnegative".

Given this situation, the approach of least resistance is to say that "derivatives" are two-sided limits, and if you want to talk about some other **generalization** of the derivative concept, you're certainly welcome to do so, but you have to call it something else! And people have done so in various directions: see [subderivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative), [weak derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_derivative), [symmetric derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_derivative), [Dini derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini_derivative), and most importantly, since it's your question: [right derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-differentiability).

Answer (score 0):

Think about the differentiability of the absolute value function. If you want to consider "how fast is $y$ changing as $x$ changes?" at $x=0$, it depends on which "side" of the absolute value function you look at. For negative $x$, $y$ is decreasing as $x$ increases, but for positive $x$, $y$ increases as $x$ increases. So at $x=0$ it doesn't really make sense to consider the rate at which $y$ changes as $x$ changes, as it depends on which "side" the change in $x$ occurs. Hopefully this helps you to see why we require both the left- and right-hand limits of the difference quotient to exist and be equal.

Comment: I think my issue is that I think of "slope of a point" as "how will y change with x" "going into the future," as a result of the slope of the point in question that came before all those points, which is why we say its *that* point's slope, if that makes any sense. I guess I don't understand how a left-hand derivative is even "the slope at this point" if the point didn't happen yet. I hope that makes things clearer as to what I'm thinking...

Comment: @hawexp I think I see what you're saying. But a general function $f(x)$ doesn't necessarily have a concept of "time" accompanying it, if that makes sense. We don't consider "going into the future" when taking the limit. What we care about is how the function behaves as you approach the point in question - from either direction! Perhaps it would benefit you more to think of the derivative of $f$ as representing the rate of change of $f$, rather than the derivative at a point as being the "slope" at that point.

Comment: Do we then require the double-sided limit only to avoid ambiguity as to what side we're talking about?

Comment: @hawexp in essence, yes. In practice it is also not particularly helpful to only have a derivative that exists on one side - many important theorems from calculus will fail if a function is not differentiable from both sides. But if you would like to think of the double-sided limit needing to exist in order to ensure that the function is changing the same way no matter which side we approach from, I think that is a fine idea to start with.

Comment: I see. That makes things a lot clearer. I thought there was some mathematical truth to needing a double-sided limit. Also, do you mean that those theorems will fail if a function isn't differentiable from both sides, or that if it's not differentiable (left and right-hand limits are different)? (Wouldn't the only case of a function not being differentiable from both sides at *a* be if it was discontinuous at *a*?)

Comment: @hawexp Theorems requiring differentiability may fail if both the left- and right-handed derivatives exist, but are not equal. They will certainly fail if the derivative does not exist in the first place (i.e. at least one of the one-sided limits does not exist). And no, not necessarily. There are some exotic functions you could cook up such as $f(x)=x\sin(1/x)$ for $x\neq0$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x=0$. This is continuous at $x=0$ but not differentiable there.